# Editing the environment variable

Tags: environment-variables

I have been trying to edit the environment variable. I had read [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables) and in the section of **Persistent environment variable ->System-wide environment variables** it is written to change the */etc/environment* file, but even after doing that the variable is same as before.
But when I echo $PATH as root user the change is reflected. I have read many questions regarding this on the site but many of the answers given are not recommended according to the article given in the link above.

Answer (score 1):

Did you log yourself out after the change and log in again? The changes will only be visible then. That would also explain why root can see the changes.

Comment: Yeah I have tried that but still the $PATH variable is not changed.And also the $PATH variable for root user is very much different form the non sudo $PATH variable. Here I have a [snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/efdD0lP.jpg)

Comment: Can you make sure that your `$PATH` variable is not set in any other startup script/file like `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.profile` or `~/.pam_environment`? Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Changing the `PATH` in `/etc/environment` otherwise works for me at least under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.